# Adding short text/badge/icon for a user

Tags: mattermost

Is there a way to show a sub headline or icon for each user? We are trying to show which team each user belongs to. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no in-built way of doing so. You can, however, create a plugin to add any metadata you like to a user's profile popover, including the team(s) ther are a member of.